# Install DotNet Framework 2.0 and Vc++Redist 2008 using NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have an application setup made using NSIS. The application needs DotNet 2.0 and VC++Redist 2008 to run. Currently i am installing these dependencies separately.I need a way to install DotNet Framework and Vc++Redist 2008 from within my NSIS Scirpt if not present on the system(if present installer should skip the dependencies). Need some piece of script and a step by step procedure to do this. Kindly help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

You should try the search engine before asking a question that was already asked, here and on the [NSIS wiki](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Category:Code_Examples):

- [how to detect if CV redist is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442935/nsisdetecting-whether-vs2005-runtimes-are-installed/1442950#1442950) (for VC2005)
- [how to detect VC2008 redist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442935/nsisdetecting-whether-vs2005-runtimes-are-installed/1442950#1442950) (to get the specific vc2008 class id)

Also:

- [How to perform a silent install of the Visual C++ 2008 redistributable packages](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2009/03/26/9513328.aspx).

  Basically you need something like

  ```
  ExecWait '$TEMP\vcredist_x86_SP1.exe /Q' $0
  DetailPrint "-- vcredist_x86_SP1.exe runtime exit code = '$0'"
  ```
- [How to check for an installed version of dotnet](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/How_to_ensure_a_required_version_of_.NET_Framework_is_installed)
- [Embedding other installers](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Embedding_other_installers) with exemples for dotnet, and other third party components